# Incremental hashing of sets

Tags: hash, set

What is a good way to incrementally hash sets of elements? This has to happen so that elements can be added and removed in any order, and still equal sets have the same hash. The intent is to be able to quickly find a set or its slight modifications from a collection of sets.

**On a vector-space approach to a combining operator**

Here is something that does not work. The b-bit integers integers can be thought of as a vector space V over the GF(2), where the addition is the XOR-operator (e.g. 10 + 11 = 01), and the multiplication by a 0 or 1 is the component-wise logical-AND (e.g. 1 * 10 = 10, 0 * 10 = 00). One can make a random (but fixed) mapping of the elements to b-bit integers E = {e_1, ..., e_b}, and then compute the hash of a set by summing the hashes of the elements together. In so doing, it has to made sure that the E forms a basis of the vector space V; otherwise the hash is not able to use all values of the b-bit integers.

The problem with this technique is that if the use subset of the E-basis does not have, say, a non-zero first component for any basis vector e_i, then the resulting hash can not be odd. Similar problems follow depending on which subset of the basis vectors is in use. In summary, XOR should not be used to find the hash of a set. Using the normal summation + probably is not any better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to augment a red-black tree so that each node contains the combined hash of the subtree rooted at that node (always left child hash combined with the current node hash with the right child hash). This allows to find the hash of all elements in constant time (the hash of the root node), while not affecting the properties of the red-black tree otherwise. It is possible to create a generic red-black tree implementation which allows to automatically update the hierarchical information in the nodes, where the update rule is specified by the user of the data structure. Since red-black trees may be rotated when they are rebalanced, this implies that the hash combination function must be associative. In the paper "Hashing with SL2" by Tillich and Zémor one can find a hash function which has an associative hash combination function (matrix multiplication). I'm not sure whether this has an acceptable performance though.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem. The application is a hash of all of memory as it is written. When 1 byte changes I don't want to have to rescan all of memory to update the hash.

A [tree of hashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree) would definitely work, but I feel like there must be a simpler way.

I'm not sure I understand your issue with xor/add. As far as I understand it you're saying if you hash your set elements to e.g. a 32-bit number but all of the hashes have the same bit in a particular position (e.g. the lowest bit is always 1) then that bit will be useless in the hash.

That doesn't matter though. Hashes are probabilistic. There's no guarantee that any hash function will use all possible outputs or that there won't be a collision.

For extra safety you could use add *and* xor (double the length of the hash).

You could also use the sum of the number of bits. Or even the sum of bits in different subsets of the bit positions - xor is the limit of this when only using one bit position).

Here's some example code in Rust:

```
use std::fmt::Display;

#[derive(Default)]
struct MemHash {
    xor: u32,
    add: u32,
    bitcount: u8,
    bitcount_even: u8,
    bitcount_odd: u8,
}

impl MemHash {
    pub fn add(&mut self, value: u32) {
        self.xor ^= value;
        self.add = self.add.wrapping_add(value);
        self.bitcount = self.bitcount.wrapping_add(value.count_ones() as u8);
        self.bitcount_even = self.bitcount_even.wrapping_add((value & 0x55555555).count_ones() as u8);
        self.bitcount_odd = self.bitcount_odd.wrapping_add((value & 0xAAAAAAAA).count_ones() as u8);
    }
    pub fn remove(&mut self, value: u32) {
        self.xor ^= value;
        self.add = self.add.wrapping_sub(value);
        self.bitcount = self.bitcount.wrapping_sub(value.count_ones() as u8);
        self.bitcount_even = self.bitcount_even.wrapping_sub((value & 0x55555555).count_ones() as u8);
        self.bitcount_odd = self.bitcount_odd.wrapping_sub((value & 0xAAAAAAAA).count_ones() as u8);
    }
    pub fn value(&self) -> u128 {
        (self.xor as u128) | ((self.add as u128) << 32) | ((self.bitcount as u128) << 64) | ((self.bitcount_even as u128) << 72) | ((self.bitcount_odd as u128) << 80)
    }
}

impl Display for MemHash {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        f.write_fmt(format_args!("{}", self.value()))
    }
}
```

Obviously it's not going to be as good as a "proper" hash in terms of quality but for my application (testing) I think it should be fine.